# Function which determines graph's vertex

Tags: java, graph, nullpointerexception

I have a trouble with java's NullPointerException. My function gets Vertex's number and returns a Vertex (I already have such class). Here is my code

```
public class Graph {
private Set<Vertex> vertices;

public Vertex getVertexByNumber(int number) {
        Vertex answer = new Vertex(number);
        for( Vertex v : vertices ) {
            if(v.getNumber() == number) {
                answer = v;
                break;
            }
        }
        answer = null;

        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 6):

Why `answer = null;`?

Because of this statement method `getVertexByNumber` will always return `null`.

Comment: Just as an addition to this good answer, the OP might benefit from not initializing the answer: `Vertex answer;`, that way he is assured that if the Vertex is found the answer has a value, otherwise it is null. Versus attempting to set it to null himself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do. But if you want your function to create a new vertex if there is no vertex with `number` value, you can write:

```
public Vertex getVertexByNumber(int number) {
    Vertex answer;

    for (Vertex v : vertices) {
        if (v.getNumber() == number) {
            answer = v;
            break;
        }
    }

    return answer == null ? new Vertex(number) : answer;
}
```

You can also write

```
public Vertex getVertexByNumber(int number) {

    for (Vertex v : vertices) {
        if (v.getNumber() == number) {
            return v;
        }
    }

    return new Vertex(number);
}
```

Otherwise, there is no need to give an initial value to `answer`, you just need to declare it:

```
public Vertex getVertexByNumber(int number) {
    Vertex answer;

    for (Vertex v : vertices) {
        if (v.getNumber() == number) {
            answer = v;
            break;
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

or

```
public Vertex getVertexByNumber(int number) {

    for (Vertex v : vertices) {
        if (v.getNumber() == number) {
            return v;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```